# What happens when multi thread program creates new processes?

Tags: c, multithreading, process, pthreads

I am a bit confused I would like to know in detail, what happens if a C program with more than one thread creates new processes. Does the behaviour depends on which thread is creating new processes or how many threads create new processes?

Comment: Lots of things happen. We can't really explain to you everything from ground zero. So your question needs to be a bit more specific than asking for "what happens". But for starters you may want to read the [`fork` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) followed by the [`pthread_atfork` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_atfork). The "Rationale" section for the latter in particular may help you. If not, please clarify your question.

Comment: More specific question: what happens if a C program with more than one thread creates new processes. Ignore the second part.

Comment: That's not really more specific. You are still asking a very broad "what happens". What happens (on Linux) is that each create results in a new process with one thread and the address space contents duplicated from the parent process. But there are many details and subtleties as described in the above man pages. If there is something specific you don't understand then ask that. Otherwise asking "what happens" is a bit broad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With pthreads, only the calling thread is forked in the new process when `fork` is called.

From the [Linux man page](http://www.unix.com/man-page/Linux/2/fork/):

> **The child process is created with a single thread--the one  that 
>   called  fork().**   The     entire  virtual  address  space of the parent
>   is replicated in the child, including the       states of mutexes, 
>   condition  variables,  and  other  pthreads  objects;  the  use  of
>   pthread_atfork(3) may be helpful for dealing with problems that this
>   can cause.

There are however some versions of `fork` on Solaris that duplicate all threads.

From the [Solaris man page](http://www.unix.com/man-page/OpenSolaris/2/fork/):

> A  call to forkall() or forkallx() replicates in the child process
>   all of the threads (see
>          thr_create(3C) and pthread_create(3C)) in the parent process. A call to fork1() or forkx()
>          replicates only the calling thread in the child process.
>
> A  call to fork() is identical to a call to fork1(); only the calling
>   thread is replicated in the child process. This is the POSIX-specified
>   behavior for fork().
>
> In releases of Solaris prior to Solaris 10, the behavior of fork()
>   depended on whether  or  not  the  application was linked with the
>   POSIX threads library. When linked with -lthread  (Solaris Threads)
>   but not linked with -lpthread (POSIX Threads), fork() was  the  same 
>   as  forkall().   When  linked with -lpthread, whether or not also
>   linked with -lthread, fork()  was the same as fork1().

Comment: @ConorWhyman fork and relatives are one of several ways to create a new process. Behavior of other process start methods varies from `fork()`. Additionally OSes that don't support `fork()` natively will have very different start process behaviors.